# Manipulating Dictionary Values Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with the following values.

```
d = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}

print d['c']
```

This would print 2.

How would I go about changing the value for a given key word? So that when the keyword 'c' was given it would return something besides 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just set it using the key:

```
>>> d = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
>>> print d['c']
2
>>> d['c'] = 9000
>>> print d['c']
9000
```